# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in kendo ui

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kendo ui popup which sends a request to an action method. The action method returns json and then my code breaks in the `kendo.all.min.js` file and the error method says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

My kendo code below:-

```
var cloudStore = new kendo.data.DataSource({
//batch: true,
pageSize: 25,
transport: {
    create: {
        url: "/Admin/AddCloudStore", //(/ControllerName/ActionName)
        type: "POST"
    },
    update: {
        url: "/Admin/UpdateCloudStore",
        type: "POST"
    },
    parameterMap: function (data, operation) {

        console.table(data);
        var result = {};
        // For update and create send the entire object
        if (operation === "update" || operation === "create") {

            return data;
            //return JSON.stringify({ service: data });
        }
        return null;
    }
},
schema: {
    model: cloudStoreModel,
    errors: "error"
},
error: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
});
```

Am I suppose to return something else from the action? Any help on the issue would be appreciated

**Edit:** Okay seems like the problem is with what I am return from my .net action method. Adding my action method below:-

```
public ActionResult AddCloudStore(DataAccess.Model.domain_config_cloud store)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DataAccess.Model.CondadoMediaVault())
        {
            if (store.cld_cmp_key <= 0) store.cld_cmp_key = Session["sel_domain_key"].ConvertToLong();

            var list = context.domain_config_cloud.Where(x => x.cld_cmp_key == store.cld_cmp_key && x.cld_is_active && x.cld_category == "primary").ToList();

            if (list.Count > 0)
                return Json("There is already a primary cloud store.");  //returning string

            long user_key = 0;
            long.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Session["user"]), out user_key);

            var maxKey = context.domain_config_cloud.OrderByDescending(x => x.cld_key).FirstOrDefault();
            if (maxKey == null || maxKey.cld_key == 0)
                return Json("Error");  //returning string
            else
                store.cld_key = maxKey.cld_key + 1;

            context.domain_config_cloud.Add(store);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MediaVault.BLL.ErrorLoggging.DbExceptionLog.LogError(ex);
    }

    return Json(store);  //returning object
}
```

So the `kendo ui` code breaks when a string is returned from the action method. If an object is returned the code does not break. What is the exact return type which is expected by kendo ui?

Comment: Try to stringify return data. Also, try to add in `crate` a complete function: `complete: function(response, error)` and see what you get

Comment: Tried stringify but the error is still there. Where exactly do I add the `complete`?

Comment: `crate: {
type: "POST", complete: function(response, error){}
}`

Comment: edited my question to add more information

Comment: I never worked with aps.net, but I'm guessing that JSON is not formated well. Or try to add dataType : "json". After type: 'POST'